# git: patch only parts of older revision of a file

Tags: git, patch

I commited a copy of "main.c" to my repository. I then deleted 5 whole functions to see what happens. I want 2 of those functions back. Can I do something like this:

```
$ git make-patch main.c --interactive > patch_to_add_back_functions.patch
#interactively choose the functions I want.
$ patch main.c patch_to_add_back_funcitons.patch
```

Is there a way to accomplish that? Either via a patch generation or via whatever would be the most git way of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `git checkout -p` you can selectively discard changes in your working tree - it's very useful for just the situation you describe, I've found.  A couple of other notes might be of interest:

- As a clarification, when I say "selectively discard changes", strictly speaking that should be "selectively change parts of the file back to their state in the index".  However, if you haven't staged any changes since the last commit, the state in the index will be the same as in the last commit.
- As with the other interactive `-p` options in git, you can press <kbd>s</kbd> to split the patch down further, or, if you need to discard changes at an even finer level, pressing <kbd>e</kbd> will let you edit the patch directly.  (The latter can be rather confusing at first, however.)